# esp32, platformio A fatal error occurred: Packet content transfer stopped (received 8 bytes) *** [upload] Error 2

Tags: esp32, uploading, error, platformio, vscode

When i try to upload code to the esp32 the following error shows up in the command line:

**A fatal error occurred: Packet content transfer stopped (received 8 bytes).**

I use platformio in VScode the platform.ini file looks like this:

```
    [env:esp-wrover-kit]
    platform = espressif32
    board = esp-wrover-kit
    framework = arduino
    upload_port = COM4
    monitor_speed = 115200
```

Here's the code i'm trying to upload:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("init");
}

void loop() {
}
```

It's an esp32-wrover-dev from freenove. When i unplug it and plug it back in it starts to write random stuff to the serial monitor, when i attempt an upload it stops but it also gives me the error above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone wondering, i found out it means that there's some kind of disconnect between the computer from which your uploading and the file system. Essentially, the esp32 is broken.

Comment: Reducing upload speed to 11520 worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve this issue by detaching jumpers that i had connected to the GPIO 12/13 pins during upload.

After uploading they can be attached again.
See this github issue: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/2415

Comment: I was using GPIO 12 and detaching it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error when trying to upload a sketch from Arduino IDE to a TTGO T-Display, found that I could resolve this by changing the upload speed from the default of 921600 to 115200.

After doing that it uploaded just fine with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Hi all I found I got this error because my FTDI adapter was in 3.3V mode, not 5V as soon as I set it to 5V the issue was resolved and it programmed fine. One more thing to check before you scrap your ESP32.

Mick

Comment: so an est32 should be powered with 3.3 V. 5 V will damage it.

Comment: Hi I was using the CAM module which has pins marked as 5V so maybe dont do that if powering the IC direct. Apparently it has less issues at 5V. Thanks.